# Definition Of Electric Flux

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, definition

I have some confusion in definition of electric flux .

I have been told that *No. of electric field lines passing through a surface area gives/represents electric flux* but if suppose $n$ number of electric field lines of two different electric fields of same magnitude but at different angles to area element cross it then by this definition flux of both through surface should be same which is wrong as we see from formula of flux

Shouldn't it  be *No. of electric field lines passing normally to the surface area gives/represents electric flux* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal definition of the flux of a vector field $\mathbf E$ through some surface $S$ is given by

$$\iint_S\mathbf E\cdot\text d\mathbf a$$

where $\text d\mathbf a$ is a vector of magnitude equal to the area $\text da$ and direction normal to the surface $S$.

So yes, you do need to consider the direction of the field.

The "number of field lines" description is a conceptual way to understand it, but that is about as far as it goes. As you note, this doesn't take direction into account. Also, you have to define what your "number of field lines" means, as the number of field lines one decides to uses is subjective.

Comment: What if we use the phrase  _ relative number of field lines_

Comment: @LalitTolani It depends on what you mean by that

Comment: Yes you are right it 's just a way of understanding it

Answer (score 1):

"Shouldn't it be No. of electric field lines passing normally to the surface area gives/represents electric flux ?"

No, because the number of lines of flux crossing the area is proportional to the flux through the area, and it doesn't matter in which direction the flux passes through the area, as long as it gets through.

The number of lines of flux represents the flux rather than the *flux density*, which is a vector that is essentially the same as the field strength vector $\vec E$). See Biophysicist's answer.

Comment: I don't say that electric field should pass normally to the surface , there's a misunderstanding.

Comment: I meant  No. of electric field lines corresponding to component of electric field along area vector  passing normally to the surface area gives/represents electric flux

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do need to consider the direction and essentially you have to calculate the flux for each electric field separately and then perform scalar addition to get total flux.
And no ,it can pass at any angle not necessarily normally.
Flux is given by the formula ϕ=EAcosΘ or ϕ=∬⋅d .So number of field lines is a rough estimate .To sum up flux is a scalar quantity which is the dot product of two vectors so taking direction into account is important and we need to calculate flux for different electric field differently and add them up to get the total flux(with proper signs).